# Backup SQL database from secondary linux server

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I took over a website at a less-than-optimal hoster with no backups yet.
I do have an FTP-access and I know the database access parameters of the installed web-app to the MySQL server, but I don't have access to the MySQL interface or the underlying server.

I would like to do an automated backup to a Linux server under my control.

I can download all data via FTP, zip it and store it on a backed up storage.

How to do this for the database?
As an initial solution I installed phpMyAdmin and did a manual backup, but I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqldump to back up a remote MySQL database.

Suppose your MySQL database is on a host called "dbhost". You can reach that host over the network from your new Linux host.

Run this command on your new Linux host:

```
$ mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases --host dbhost > datadump.sql
```

(You might also need to add the `--user` and `--password` options.)

You can automate any command you can run at the command-line. Put it in a shell script. Then you an invoke the script for example from cron.

Comment: Thanks, sadly I just noticed the hoster does not allow remote access to the database (which is a positive thing from a security standpoint!). Therefore, this does not fullfill my needs, but is a correct answer nonetheless. I will accept it if I dont get a more satisfying one.

Comment: Yep, when you use commodity hosting plans, you sacrifice a lot of potential features. They have to make hosting one-size-fits-all to make it as cheap as they do.

Comment: Yes, for my other websites I use a much more leveled solution (and I'm also using their VPS as a backup server). But in this case some stuff is already provided.